# How can I update LAT/LONG variables and refresh pins based on the new location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I am trying to make a map that will display specific monuments as I travel the state. I want it to update the monuments available when I move the map on my screen.
I am using a PHP page with GET parameters to return the points available from my db.
I currently have it set on a starting point, but I cannot figure out how to make it update after I drag the map. I am wanting it to update based on the center of the map, Wherever that may be at dragend.
This is the map page with the JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>NGS Dynamic Map with Google Maps</title>
    <style>
      #main{
        height:90%;
      }
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
    <script>



        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.27,-98.87),
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    var NewMapCenter = map.getCenter();
    var vlat = NewMapCenter.lat();
    var vlong = NewMapCenter.lng();


          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('makePoints.php?lat=' + vlat + '&long=' + vlong, function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var county = markerElem.getAttribute('county');
              var state = markerElem.getAttribute('state');
          var elevation = markerElem.getAttribute('elevation');
          var data_source = markerElem.getAttribute('data_source');

              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = "PID# " + name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = county + " County"
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = elevation + " (US Survey Ft.)"
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));


              var newlink = document.createElement('a');
              newlink.textContent = data_source
              newlink.setAttribute('target', '_new');
              newlink.setAttribute('href', data_source);
              infowincontent.appendChild(newlink);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD_wB5WVi2nupVm9WzQ9C8Px_iYB1JZJv0&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was thinking I could just keep the variables  of my downloadUrl parameters set and update them on the dragend event which would also reinitialize the function that calls and processes the `downloadUrl()` data. Then the map would be updated, but i'm not sure this is the right way to make it happen.

Also the downloadUrl page simply takes the lat/long passed by GET and accesses my db then grabs everything within a  10 mile radius of the lat/long passed through to it. The PHP returns XML.
I really don't know enough .js to understand how to make this work. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you need's an event listener for dragend on the map, to repeat the ajax request to your PHP file.  Make the call to that ajax request happen in its own function.  Make your `map` variable global, so it can be accessed in both functions.

Something like this:

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.27, -98.87),
        zoom: 12
    });

    getPoints(30.27, -98.87);

    map.addListener('dragend', function() {
        var NewMapCenter = this.getCenter();
        var vlat = NewMapCenter.lat();
        var vlong = NewMapCenter.lng();
        getPoints(vlat, vlong);
    });
}

function getPoints(vlat, vlong) {
    downloadUrl('makePoints.php?lat=' + vlat + '&long=' + vlong, function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        markers.forEach(function(markerElem) {
            var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
            var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
            var county = markerElem.getAttribute('county');
            var state = markerElem.getAttribute('state');
            var elevation = markerElem.getAttribute('elevation');
            var data_source = markerElem.getAttribute('data_source');

            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

            var infowincontent = // ... etc

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point
            });
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        });
    }); 
}
```